# How to making a global Publisher?

Tags: swift, combine

I try to maing a global publisher,like:

```
@Published var counter = 0
```

But here is a error:

```
Property wrappers are not yet supported in top-level code
```

How to share global Publisher variables between models？

Comment: This is the wrong path, investigate @EnvironmentObject

Answer (score 1):

If you want a global variable that publishes a value in a similar way to an `@Published` property you can do

```
var counter = CurrentValueSubject<Int,Never>(0)

let subscription = counter.sink { print("The counter is \($0)") }
counter1.value = 3
```

But if you are using SwiftUI then as Joakim Danielson pointed out in comments you should look into making the value part of the Environment rather than having a global.

That solution would look something like:

```
private struct EnvironmentCounter: EnvironmentKey {
    typealias Value = Int
    static var defaultValue: Int = 0
    static let farReachingCounter: String = "Far Reaching Counter"
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var farReachingCounter: Int {
        get { self[EnvironmentCounter.self] }
        set { self[EnvironmentCounter.self] = newValue }
    }
}

struct LeafView : View {
    @Environment(\.farReachingCounter) var counter : Int

    var body: some View {
        Text("The counter is \(counter)")
    }
}

struct IntermediateView : View {
    var body: some View {
        LeafView()
    }
}

struct TopLevelView: View {
    @State var counter = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            IntermediateView()
            HStack {
                Button(action: { counter = counter + 1 }) {
                    Text("Increment")
                }

                Button(action: { counter = counter - 1 }) {
                    Text("Decrement")
                }
            }
        }.environment(\.farReachingCounter, counter)
    }
}

PlaygroundSupport.PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: TopLevelView())
```

This code declares an `EnvironmentKey` that views can use to pull values out of the Environment.  In this case the key is `farReachingCounter`.

Then it declares an extension on `EnvironmentValues` that gets and sets the value in and gets the value from the environment.

Finally I show a SwiftUI hierarchy where the `TopLevelView` defines the counter value for its whole hierarchy.  There is an `IntermediateView` that doesn't reference the court counter at all (it's just there to show that the counter passes down the view hierarchy through the environment). Then the `LeafView` shows how you can pull a custom value out of the environment.

The `farReachingCounter` is not global to the whole module, but it is part of the SwiftUI environment from the `TopLevelView` down.

Comment: Look at the code below - you don't need environment variables

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :

```
class Counter: ObservableObject {
    @Published var counter = 0
    
    static var shared = Counter.init()
    
    private init() { //Just to hide the method
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You can access it anywhere - both views and models

Comment: You've taken the first solution I gave you where I used `CurrentValueSubject` and you've hidden it behind a singleton object and an `@Published` property wrapper.  It's a perfectly valid solution, and probably has advantages when it comes to things like unit testing.  But it boils down to the same thing.